# How is a unique MAC address possible?

Tags: wifi

I just read about the mac address at wiki.

The mac address should uniquely identify a wifi device and is a 48-bit number separated in two parts, while the first 24-bit are reserved for manufacturer identification. The last 24-bit are actually the unique ones, which can be set through the manufacturer.

2^24 = 16,7 millions

How can this be a unique id, when for example Apple alone is selling over 50 million wifi devices in one quarter, according to [techcrunch.com](http://techcrunch.com/2013/10/28/apple-q4-2013-iphone-ipad-mac-sales/). I would also think, that Apple has only one manufacturer for their wifi chips. Also today cameras, cars, watches.. ah everything has wifi.

They could gather a new manufacturer id, but it seems to me, that every manufacturer has really only one. Also the relation of 24-bit manufacturer and 24-bit device I don't understand. Why should there be as many manufacturers as devices.

So, how can this be a unique id?

Comment: How did you come up with 24^2 number. A mac address consists of 12 hex digits hence 12^16 different numbers...

Comment: 6 hex digits are reserved for manufacturer id. So it would only be 6^16. But this seems enough. Thank you, I think that was my error in thinking about this.

Comment: Nope, thats also wrong. It would be 16^6 and that would be again 16,7 million.

Answer (score -2):

First 2^24 are purchasable, so technically 2^48 is the limit.

> This 48-bit address space contains potentially 2^48 or 281,474,976,710,656 possible MAC addresses.

Comment: But the first 2^24 are reserved for the manufacturer. That means the random id is only 2^24, which are 16,7 million. Which basically means 16 million devices per manufacturer?

Comment: First 2^24 are purchasable, so if You search for example Apple in IEEE Public MA-L listing http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/oui/public.html  You'll see they have multiple Organizationally unique identifiers.